# Vue-js remember check box choices for every question

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a quiz app. I have question selection menu and I need to save each checkbox state for each question. For example, if you were to select an answer for 1st question, I need to save your choices even if you skip to 3rd question so when you come back to 1st your old choices are still there.

Now the problem that I have is - my checkboxes aren't unique, they are same for each question. Please take a look at gif on what happens.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGBSK.gif

This is my code

```xml
<template>
  <div v-if="loading"><loader></loader></div>
  <div v-else class="main">
    <h5 class="test-title">Test</h5>
    <h5 class="choosequestion">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="list-ul" style="margin-right: 8px" />Choose question
    </h5>
    <div v-dragscroll="true" class="questionsbox">
      <!-- answered, current -->
      <input v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index" :value="index + 1" @click="chooseQuestion(index)" class="questionbox" type="button" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="ctlBtn">Restart</a>
      <a class="ctlBtn">End</a>
    </div>
    <div class="questionmain">
      <h5 class="questiontext">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="question-circle" style="margin-right: 8px" />
        {{ currentQuestion.question }}
      </h5>
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="( answer, key ) in currentQuestion.answers"
          :index="currentQuestion.key"
          :key="answer.title"
        >
          <input v-model="checkedAnswers[key]" @change="answerClick" :id="answer.title" type="checkbox" />
          <label :for="answer.title" >{{ answer.title }}</label>
        </li>
        {{ checkedAnswers }}
      </ul>
      <img
        class="questionimg"
        :src="currentQuestion.image_url"
      />
      <a class="nextBtn" @click="nextQuestion"><font-awesome-icon icon="arrow-right" style="color: black;"/></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { dragscroll } from "vue-dragscroll";
import Loader from "./Loader.vue";

export default {
  components: { Loader }, 
  name: "TestCard",
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [],
      loading: true,
      index: 0,
      checkedAnswers: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentQuestion() {
      if (this.questions !== []) {
        return this.questions[this.index];
      }
      return null;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async getQuestions() {
      this.loading = true;
      let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/test");
      let jsonResponse = await response.json();
      // put data on questions property
      this.questions = jsonResponse.questions;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    answerClick() {
      console.log("answer clicked");
    },
    chooseQuestion(index) {
      this.index = index;
    },
    nextQuestion() {
      this.index += 1;
      console.log("next question")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getQuestions();
  },
  directives: {
    dragscroll,
  },
};
</script>
```

After that, I would like to check if answers are correct when user presses on "End". How do I connect each checkbox to it's answer and question, then check it if its correct? I have `"correct: true"` in JSON for each correct answer :)

Thank you

Comment: Hi, You can use vuex state management to maintain the state for each question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing too much of your existing code you could go about mapping your answers to questions like this. No need for Vuex or more complexity.

```
<template>
  ...
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="( answer, key ) in currentQuestion.answers"
          :index="currentQuestion.key"
          :key="answer.title"
        >
// we pass the key to answerClick to be able to map the answer to the current question
          <input v-model="checkedAnswers[key]" @change="answerClick(key)" :id="answer.title" type="checkbox" />
          <label :for="answer.title" >{{ answer.title }}</label>
        </li>
        {{ checkedAnswers }}
...
</template>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "TestCard",
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [],
      loading: true,
      index: 0,
      checkedAnswers: [],
      answers: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentQuestion() {
      if (this.questions !== []) {
        return this.questions[this.index];
      }
      return null;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getQuestions() {
      this.loading = true;
      let response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/test");
      let jsonResponse = await response.json();
      // put data on questions property
      this.questions = jsonResponse.questions;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    answerClick(key) {
      console.log("answer clicked");
      if (!this.answers[this.index]) this.answers[this.index] = [] // if the current question has no answers mapped yet set an empty array 
      this.answers[this.index][key] = this.checkedAnswers[key]; // set the answer to whatever value it has currently (true, false)
    },
    chooseQuestion(index) {
      this.index = index;
      this.checkedAnswers = this.answers[this.index] ? this.answers[this.index] : []; // set the checkedAnswers to what we can find in our mapping, if there is nothing to find use an empty array
    },
    nextQuestion() {
      this.index += 1;
      this.checkedAnswers = []; // unset the checked answers for the next question
      console.log("next question")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getQuestions();
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Problem 1: 

I get 

Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: key is not defined"

When clicking on answer

and I get

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined"

When clicking on Next Question button when I have selected an answer. If i just click it without choosing an answer, no errors happen.

Problem 2:

Chosen answers only save when I press next question. If I choose question via question select menu, they don't get saved.

nextQuestion() - saves questions
answerClick() - doesn't save

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing `key` to the `answerClick(key)` function I outlined?
Here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-euclid-hoxti?file=/src/components/TestCard.vue) and it works fine (except that font-awesome-icons arent found, i didnt install them in the example but that doesn't matter).

Comment: Hey Braks, hope you're doing well :) It was my fault, I am not sure where but I copied your code one more time and now it works. I fixed `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined"` by checking if the current question index equals to questions array length. You can't click next question if you are at the last question. `if(this.index == this.questions.length - 1) { return 0; }`